# Asp.Net MVC 4 Controller to update database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

Model

```
public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public bool OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string AdminStatus { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult CheckOut()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var userid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
                var data = _bbdb.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderStatus == false && x.UserId == userid).ToList();

                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    _bbdb.Orders.Add(new Orders
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        UserId = item.UserId,
                        ProductId = item.ProductId,
                        Quantity = item.Quantity,
                        Price = item.Price,
                        OrderStatus = true,
                        OrderNumber = item.UserId + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                        AdminStatus = item.AdminStatus,
                        PaymentStatus = item.PaymentStatus,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Today
                    });

                    _bbdb.SaveChanges();

                }
            }

            var cartdata = GetCartItems();
            return PartialView("_CartTable", cartdata);
        }
```

How can I change this bit code  `_bbdb.Orders.Add(new Orders` to UPDATE instead ADD.

I thought something like `_bbdb.Orders.AddOrUpdate(new Orders` would do the trick, but I does not exist.

It is adding the right value, but I want to update the records not add new ones.

Any suggestion on how to improve or change will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how correct I am here, but try this...

_bbdb tracks the changes, so you simply need to get the item from the db, make the changes you need and then save them.

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
     item.Price = 100; //Set whatever values you need to update
}

_bbdb.SaveChanges();
```

Also, notice that the `SaveChanges()` method was moved outside of `foreach`. The context will track the changes so you don't need to call `SaveChanges` after each item is added.

Finally, I *believe* that you don't need `ToList()` after the `Where`-clause

Comment: +1, and you are correct about the LINQ `Where`. Adding a `ToList` prevents the collection from being Lazy. Here it doesn't make much difference because there is an iteration over the entire collection. What you want to avoid is `Where().ToList().Where()`